# For each not finding the correct if statement

Tags: vba

I'm trying to get it to take multiple values from an input and if there is say 2 values then to put those into SAP in two unique spots. When I run the macro with a value of "007" for example it pulls up an error in the section "If j = 7", but it should run the section "If j = 1" instead. I'm confused as to why it is doing this.
(This is not all the code just the relevant bits)

```
    Public MRP As String
    Public dNext_Monday As Date
    Public WK As String
    Public LR As Long
    Public iWindowState As Integer
    Public strEntries As String, inputArray() As String, j As Variant

strEntries = Application.InputBox("Enter multiple comma separated MRP Controllers. Ex: 007,009,016 ", "MRP Entries", Type:=2)
    If strEntries = "False" Then Exit Sub   'User canceled
    inputArray = Split(strEntries, ",")
    j = UBound(inputArray) - LBound(inputArray) + 1    

For Each j In inputArray
If j = 1 Then
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = inputArray(0)
End If
If j = 2 Then
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = inputArray(0)
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").Text = inputArray(1)
End If
```

Comment: Actually it appears you do not need the loop.  You are testing if how many items there are and using them all each if.  Just remove the loop.

Comment: yep I'm dumb I appreciate the speedy response!

Comment: @ScottCraner - I assume you meant keep the loop over the array, but remove the `If`/`End If`?

Comment: No, the OP is testing each value of J.  If there is only 1 item then do this, if there are 2 items to this, if there are 3 items then do this, and so on.  They do not need to loop since they are doing it with ifs.  That being said, I think your approach is more concise and better practice

Answer (score 1):

Not an SAP user, but try the following, iterating the array using a `For ... Next` loop with `LBound` and `UBound`, and concatenating `j` into the ID with `&`.

```
inputArray = Split(strEntries, ",")

Dim j As Long ' remove the j As Variant from earlier
For j = Lbound(inputArray) to Ubound(inputArray)
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1," & j & "]").Text = inputArray(j)
Next
```